# Node JS data persistency - is there a better way to do this other than using variables in a module?

Tags: node.js

I'm working on a facebook messenger bot in nodeJS.  My bot requires me to collect certain data from the user.  These are then stored in a database.  However I want the data that I collect to ALWAYS be available, for convenience.  For example, I'm going to ask the user what they want the bot to call them.  Let's assume they say they want to be called "Sam".  I will save this in a database but rather than having to read it from the database every time, I want to be able to store it somewhere for quick and easy access.

I have a module called user.js, which is basically just a series of variables.  I did it this way so that the user data is always available globally to all modules.  However the data has a very short lifespan.  For example if I ask the user what they want to be called, it stores the data but within a few minutes the variable "preferredName" is now undefined again.

Is there a better way to store data rather than just using a series of variables?  For example if I used a Javascript object, or an array, would that allow for better data persistence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to consider is when your program is being re-started (like you're using an auto-restart tool for your app, `nodemon`, `forever`, etc.). Each time the server restarts, your `user.js` file is reloaded and is likely empty.

Storing it in-app is a fine solution. I'd suggest a JSON object for easy user "lookup", rather than an array to search through. You'd want to make sure that:

1. It loads from the database when first initialized (good for your auto-restart tool too)
2. Changes you persist update this object as well. Either mutate the state, or re-pull from the DB. (This becoming a lot trickier if you are scaling your server into multiple node instances...)

Sometimes a "caching database" is good choice for things like this. `Redis` or `memcache` are two popular ones. Here you get the persistence outside your app, but a faster database query.

One final thing, and I couldn't tell exactly from your question, but **do not optimize too soon!** It is far simpler to just call the DB each time, every time, and you might not even notice it! And your DB instance will be able to handle that very well for a while (100's, 1000' of users?!!). Isolate those calls so that you can switch out calling the DB to calling your "cache" when the need arises, and you can progress on the good stuff of your app a lot faster, and worry about this "better way" later.

Comment: Thank you for this, it's a great answer!  Another quick question for you:  If I put this JSON object into my user.js module, can I "require" just this object, rather than the whole module?

Comment: That could be the only thing exported, I think, or you use the ES2015 syntax to just use that piece, like `var {users} = require('./users.js')` (if your file exported, `users`, `updateUser()` and `refetchAll()`)